# Installing FDT On Windows & Java JRE Issue

Tags: fdt

I have been using FlashBuilder for some time now but I recently discovered some
interesting articles that claim FDT is sweet. I'm trying to evaluate it but I
can't find a windows installer anywhere. I'm trying to use the stand-alone
version. I downloaded the zip file and I don't see an installer. The exe doesn't
work, says JRE is not there even though I have installed/updated it.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, there is no installer for FDT - just a .zip file with FDT inside.

Being told that you don't have Java available / installed is a problem.

Try this:
http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre&try=1

Below is what FDT look like when it's unzipped:

[image]